# SSH (or SFTP) upload files from OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to upload a file through terminal (didnt managed to do it trough transmit.app)

- I'm connected to SSH to my server.
- I want to sent a file from my Local desktop to my server.

That the command I'm trying :

```
scp /Users/username/Desktop/ad-blocker.sh user@IP:/var/packages/DNSServer/target/script/
```

I always have this error though " No such file or directory "

not a expert of SSH, but if I'm connected to my server to SSH, how would terminal access my local file anyway (/Users/username/Desktop/ad-blocker.sh)

Kind regards.

Comment: *now I have Permission denied* your non-root user usually does not have access to files under `/var/`. This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the path you are copying to exists.

Before executing your `scp` command, `ssh` into your remote host, `cd` to the directory, and issue the `pwd` command.  That will give you the current working directory.

Copy that to your clipboard.

Exit SSH, then re-issue the `scp` command with the directory (paste from your clipboard).

Comment: Thank, I didn't disconnect from the SSH first, now I have Permission denied, I have to review the server settings. thank you.

Comment: I've never run into that.  Must be a custom setting in sshd....